# Python argparse IndexError for passing "-a="

Tags: python, argparse

I am studying the source code of Python's `argparse` (version 3.6.7). If you are familiar with that piece of code, it will be much helpful. The following code will cause this library to raise an `IndexError`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args("-a=".split())
print(args)
```

The full error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "argparseRaiseIndexError.py", line 5, in <module>
    args = parser.parse_args("-a=".split())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1743, in parse_args
    args, argv = self.parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1775, in parse_known_args
    namespace, args = self._parse_known_args(args, namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1981, in _parse_known_args
    start_index = consume_optional(start_index)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/argparse.py", line 1881, in consume_optional
    option_string = char + explicit_arg[0]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

If I make it right, the correct behavior is to report an error to the user for bad input such as "-a=", rather than raising an exception.

I reviewed the code for a while and figure out the reason finally. This is because `'='` signals an `explicit_arg`, and they assume this string is never empty. In fact, they never test for that, but rather test whether it is `None`. In the function `consume_optional` where the exception is triggered we can see that:

```
# if there is an explicit argument, try to match the
# optional's string arguments to only this
if explicit_arg is not None:
    # bla bla...
    option_string = char + explicit_arg[0] # Empty!
```

Is this is an old bug? How should I report this bug?

Comment: There haven't been any code changes in this section of code in a long time.  It probably dates back to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a combination of several pathological cases

```
In [177]: import argparse
In [178]: p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [179]: a1=p.add_argument('--aa')
In [180]: p.parse_args(['--a=10'])
Out[180]: Namespace(aa='10')
In [181]: p.parse_args(['--a='])
Out[181]: Namespace(aa='')
In [182]: a2=p.add_argument('--bb', action='store_true')
In [183]: p.parse_args(['--aa='])
Out[183]: Namespace(aa='', bb=False)
In [184]: p.parse_args(['--bb='])
usage: ipython3 [-h] [--aa AA] [--bb]
ipython3: error: argument --bb: ignored explicit argument ''
...
In [185]: a3=p.add_argument('-c')
In [186]: a4=p.add_argument('-d', action='store_true')
In [187]: p.parse_args(['-c='])
Out[187]: Namespace(aa=None, bb=False, c='', d=False)
In [188]: p.parse_args(['-d='])
...
-> 1881                         option_string = char + explicit_arg[0]
   1882                         new_explicit_arg = explicit_arg[1:] or None
   1883                         optionals_map = self._option_string_actions

IndexError: string index out of range
```

It occurs with a `-a`, a short optional, and `store_true`

It's documented that long optionals (with --) may take '=value', as in `In[180]`.  And the value may be '', as in `In[181]`.

As it turns out '-c=' also works this way.  The code doesn't actually try to prevent the use of '=' with a short, even though it's not documented.  I vaguely recall looking into this either for another SO or a Python bug issue.

The use of '=' with a 'store_true' should be an error.  'store_true' doesn't take an argument.  Hence `In[184]` raises a proper error about 'explicit argument'.

The place where a short optional really differs from a long is in allowing for a following short, e.g

```
In [190]: p.parse_args(['-dc='])
Out[190]: Namespace(aa=None, bb=False, c='=', d=True)
```

So your error occurs because you use a short optional, 'store_true' and the '='.  So there's a series of errors that together fall through the cracks.  I'll have to study that function a little more carefully to identify exactly the sequence.

I agree that the correct action would be to raise a `ArgumentError` resulting a formal error as in `In[184]`.  But because it is caused the coincidence of several error, I'm also tempted recommend ignoring it.

You could report it at https://bugs.python.org/.  I've tried to follow all argparse bugs, though I haven't contributed a formal patch in quite some time.

===

In `_parse_optional(self, arg_string):`, the '-a=' causes it to

```
return action, option_string, explicit_arg
(<the a action>, '-a', '')
```

(this function doesn't distinguish between a '-a=' and '--aa='; some think it should.)

In `consume_optional`, we fetch that tuple

```
action, option_string, explicit_arg = option_tuple
```

`explicit_arg` is not None, `arg_count` is 0, and it is a single-dash option, it "try to parse out more single-dash options".

It puts the current action back on the `action_tuples` list as (, [], 'a')

It tries construct a new short optional, e.g.  `'-'+explicit_arg[0]`, while putting the rest back in `explicit_arg[1:]`.

Normally this step is processing `-cdefoo` as '-c', '-d', '-e=foo'.

There are some details here that I'm not quite following.  BUT, if this works in 99.999% of the cases, and only fails in a triple-pathological one, I'm hesitant to change anything.  The chances of introducing a further error, or backward incompatibilities, are just too great.  No full time developer has taken `argparse` under his care.

Comment: +1 for providing the bug report link. I have run the debugger many times over the call sequence that makes this happen so I am clear about why it happened. In my opinion they spend too much to all the other things and ignore such corner case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term **explicit_arg** mixes two different things: an argument introduced by '=' (I call it the *equal case*) and an arguemnt concatenated to a short option (I call it the *sticky case*). The first case allows both long and short option (--foo=bar or -f=bar) while the latter is only valid with short option (-L/usr/lib only). And there is another thing here: an empty explicit_arg is not a 100% error, as you have shown. The code tried to reinterprete the meaning of explicit_arg when the leading short option does not take an argument, but unfortunately the first case (equal case) comes to disturb its work by rendering an empty explicit_arg. That why I deliberately passed it `"-a="` not `"-afoo"`. With stick case, you can't render an empty `explicit_arg` (you can't do a `split` on it), but with equal case, you can. In short, these two cases shouldn't be mixed from the beginning, or at least, should be distinguished at proper moments.

The same problem can cause other interest bugs: you can fool the library to believe an explicit argument was an option! See below:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-a", action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-b", action="store_false")
print(parser.parse_args("-a=b".split()))
```

will produce:

```
Namespace(a=True, b=False)
```

since the `'b'` here is an `explict_arg` and its meaning was reinterpreted to be an option. In my opinion, the correct behavior should be:

```
usage: ShortOptioinWithEqualSignExplicitArg.py [-h] [-a]
ShortOptioinWithEqualSignExplicitArg.py: error: argument -a: ignored explicit argument 'b'
```

as when the second `add_argument` was commented out.

In conclusion, the mixture of equal case and stick case is the primary problem. To fix that, my recommendation is to split the concept `explicit_arg` into `sticky_arg` and `equal_arg`. Only do reinterpretation to parse more short option when it is a `sticky_arg`. This should eliminate two bugs I found here.

Comment: This is an interesting approach.  This section of the code could well be more complicated or hacky than it needs to be.  I know usage formatter is unnecessarily brittle and could use a full rewrite.  I should review which related cases, if any, are handled in the unittest file, `test_argparse.py`.

Comment: @hpaulj Agree. Code of argparse.py is quite subtle in some places. Much code isn't very straightforward. You need to guess and do experiments. Hope for a cleaner code.